# download large records using jquery or some better alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my User Interface, there is an Advanced Search section where user selects 7 different things as shown in the diagram below and based on these parameters, a web service is called. The webservice returns the search results in a JSON format and those records are displayed in a tabular format in the User Interface.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/6HRU8)(using jqxwidget)

So I have a `Export to Excel` button below the tabular section where all records are displayed, just like shown in the jsfiddle above.

If I have to download the records in excel/csv format as soon as user clicks the download button, is there something better than using jQXwidgets that is used in the JSFiddle?

The reason I want to go away from jqxwidget is that they are asking to supply a URL hosted on my RHEL server and that’s causing issues to me in setting up virtualhost on Apache etc. The reason they are asking is that the records are around 87000 or more and to handle the load I need to have their solution on my server.

Here is more information regarding my UI (diagram below) and some info below it:

[image]

So at first, user sees only the `Advanced Search` section until the `Search` and `Clear` buttons. After selecting things from the drop-down boxes, user clicks on the `Search` button. This calls a search web service in the backend. A new table shows up with `Search results (81702)`as shown in the diagram above.

Below the table, I have the `Export to Excel` button. That's where I am having issues since the records are so big and jQWidget I am using is unable to handle more than 600 records. So they are asking me to host their source code file on my server and so on and so forth.

Comment: Totally, you want to ask: *How to export to excel file not using `jqwidgets`, don't you?*

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: You can also use jquery datatables checkout https://datatables.net/

Comment: @MohtishamZubair Thanks. Is that going to handle 87000 records easily?

Comment: @Tan: When you need to work with a large amount of data you can use the **[Server-Side](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)** functionality of jQuery DataTables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage data with table, I suggest to use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It's easy to manage, it also has a nice template and a lot of useful controls, such as: searching, paging, sorting, filtering... and downloading *(Excel, CSV, PDF format)*.

These are some libraries you may want to add:

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
```

Scripts:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('table').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5'
        ]
    });
</script>
```

```js
$('table').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5'
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```